# how to wait for return value from javascript in android and proceed

Tags: javascript, android

I am just a learner of Android since a week before, It might be a trivial for someone but this looks big for me as I am new to this. I searched a lot and couldn't found a straight forward question or solution. So, I dont want to spend much time in confusing and post my question here.

I am having a webview in my app, which loads a webpage. I placed a button "Generate" below webview and calling an JS function "saveData()" in that web webpage in that button's onclick. This function needs few seconds to execute and return its response based on the user's network connection speed. Then, I am showing "copy" button to copy the return value.

```
    generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            generate.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
            copy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(saveData)"); // this function needs few seconds.
            }
    });
```

I am catching the return value of the JS function as follows, and setting the value of string "JsVal"

```
    String JsVal;   
    public String getJsVal() {
        return jsVal;
    }

    public void setJsVal(String jsVal) {
        this.jsVal = jsVal;
    }

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,JsResult result) {
            Log.d("LogTag from js call method", message);
            setJsVal(message);
            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here,  copy button code is making text copied for paste to somewhere,

```
    copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ClipboardManager myClipboard;
            myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData myClip;
            myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", tVal);
            myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);                 
        }
    });
```

Problem is, if I click the generate button, immediatly copy button is available. If I click on the copy button immediatly and paste in notes app, it shows null. If I copy after 2-3 secondes its not null.

I want to show copy button after the JS return value assigned to String variable "JsVal", untill I need to show nothing.

How to do this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it using a AsyncTask in button's onClick.

You can take a look at this documentation, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

change your code as follows,

```
generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {               
        generate.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        //copy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(saveData)"); // this function needs few seconds.

        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
        runner.execute();

        }
});
```

Also you need to add the following code to get the AsyncTask works.

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            if (getVal() == null) {
                doInBackground(params);
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        copy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
    }
}
```

This is the solution you need to implement and it should work as you expected.

Comment: Thanks Mary, This is what I expected. Works like a charm.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can work. If i try something similar it ends up with a StackOverflow Exception. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        copy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
   }
});

generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {               
        generate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(saveData)"); // this function needs few seconds.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extend the onPageFinished method via WebViewClient:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Enable button
    }
});
```

Comment: Glitcher, Thanks for your answer. But,  I already tried that, but for javascript loads its not working

Comment: Interesting. Is there not another method you can use to save?

Comment: sorry, cant understand?

Comment: How about you test the contents of tVal every second, and if it's none null, copy then?

Comment: Yes, but you could try that? And once the value comes back, stop

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,JsResult result) {
                Log.d("LogTag from js call method", message);
                setJsVal(message);
                result.confirm();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress == 100) {
                    generate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    copy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```